Is it possible to construct a mdspan from a span?
Follwing code works:
std::array Array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
std::mdspan<int, std::dextents<size_t, 2>> Span(Array.data(), 4, 2 );

This one produces a compilation error:
std::array Array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
std::span sp(Array.data(), 8);
std::mdspan<int, std::dextents<size_t, 2>> Span(sp, 4, 2 );

E.g. the error on clang:
<source>:26:48: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::mdspan<int, std::dextents<size_t, 2>>' (aka 'mdspan<int, extents<unsigned long, 18446744073709551615UL, 18446744073709551615UL>>')
   26 |     std::mdspan<int, std::dextents<size_t, 2>> Span(sp), 4, 2);

<...some more lines...>

Is it possible to construct a mdspan from a span ? if yes, what am I missing ?
(it is a simplified source code, obviously we wouldn't need dynamic extents here)

Do like you do with the array?  std::mdspan<int, std::dextents<size_t, 2>> Span(sp.data(), 4, 4 );

@NathanOliver, thanks, i wasn't aware of the data() method of span....

@wohlstad, right, edited the post

@NathanOliver I think your comment deserves to be made into a proper answer. Let me know if you do not intend to do that and I will.

@wohlstad If you want to write it up go ahead

At the moment std::mdspan does not have a constructor that accepts a std::span.
But as @NathanOliver commented, std::span has a data() method to access the span's undelying data as a pointer.
It can be used in your case with std::mdspan constructor (2):
std::array Array2{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
std::span sp(Array2.data(), 8);
//-------------------------------------------------vvvvvvv--------
std::mdspan<int, std::dextents<size_t, 2>> Span2(sp.data(), 4, 2);

Live demo
